# How to call methods which are present in right side defined class. Python inheritance. multiple inheritance. Dimond scenario python inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have a class which is inherited from two other classes. When I call the methods from the child class, It always calls the method which mentioned left side in in class definition.

I know this way Python works. It first check the method in left side class and then right side class.

But now I can't change my child class definition. 
Please get me some help, how can I call same method present in "Second" class.

I am bit new to Python.
using python 2.7

```
class First(object):
    def get_details(self):
        print "This method gets called every time"
        print "I can't change my Child class structure" 

class Second(object):
    def get_details(self):
        print "But I want to call the same method of this class.. "
        print "Please let me know what can I do? How do I call method of second inherited class" 

class Child(First, Second):
    pass


child_obj = Child()
child_obj.get_details()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either call it directly:

```
Second.get_details(child_obj)
```

or use `.mro()` to get the method resolution order and chose the second parent:

```
Child.mro()[2].get_details(child_obj)
```

The method resolution order shows you search order of classes Python uses to find a method:

```
>>> Child.mro()
[__main__.Child, __main__.First, __main__.Second, object]
```

As soon as it found `get_details()` in this list it stops and uses it.

I would suggest to hide this logic in a method of `Child`:

```
class Child(First, Second):

    def get_details_second_1(self):
        """Option 1"""
        return Second.get_details(self)

    def get_details_second_2(self):
        """Option 2"""
        return Child.mro()[2].get_details(self)

child_obj = Child()
child_obj.get_details_second_1()
child_obj.get_details_second_2()
```

Comment: First one is working for this example. I don't know about "mro()" and how it works. Anyway thanks for the help, I'll search for mro()

Comment: If you want to go through a class's base classes, `__bases__` is a much safer way to do that. `mro()[2]` could easily be a grandparent instead of the second base if `First` had a parent that wasn't `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call methods directly by calling them on the class whose definition of the method you want to use:

```
Second.get_details(child_obj)
```

For a more general case where you might not know the parent classes but want to tamper with the [method resolution order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization), you can inspect said order using the [`mro`](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) method of the class:

```
Child.mro()
# [<class 'Child'>, 
#  <class 'First'>, 
#  <class 'Second'>, 
#  <class 'object'>]
```

You can intentionally skip parent classes:

```
Child.mro()[2].get_details(child_obj)
```

Or reverse the order:

```
for klass in reversed(Child.mro()):
    if hasattr(klass, 'get_details'):
        klass.get_details(child_obj)
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I got it.